# Get value from web document (intranet) input element with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, internet-explorer

I'm having trouble getting the value from an input field called "due date"

Here is my HTML and VBA code.

I resolved error 462, but I can't retrieve certain data.

Actually I'm getting an error:
Run-time error '91:
Object variable or With block variable not set

VBA:

```
Sub Dane_z_www()

Range("A1").Clear

Dim appIE As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim my_url As String
Dim TerminPlatnosci As String
Dim shellWins As SHDocVw.ShellWindows
Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument

my_url = "https://example.com"
Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium

With appIE
.Visible = True
.Navigate my_url
End With

Set shellWins = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows

For Each IE In shellWins
    If IE.Name = "Internet Explorer" Then
        Set IEObject1 = IE
        Debug.Print IE.LocationURL
        Debug.Print IE.LocationName
End If
Next

Set shellWins = Nothing
Set IE = Nothing


Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop

Set Doc = appIE.Document

'TerminPlatnosci = Trim(Doc.getelementsByName("section-36-control$xf-771$xf-784$xml_termin_platnosci-control$xforms-input-1")(0).Value)
'TerminPlatnosci = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).getElementsByName("input id")(0).getAttribute("value"))
TerminPlatnosci = Trim(Doc.querySelector("input[name='section-36-control$xf-771$xf-784$xml_termin_platnosci-control$xforms-input-1']").getAttribute("value"))
Range("A1").Value = TerminPlatnosci

appIE.Quit
Set appIE = Nothing

MsgBox "Daty zostały wczytane", , "Komunikat"

End Sub
```

HTML:

[image]

The code provides three variants that I used when trying to download the data.

1. TerminPlatnosci = Trim(Doc.getelementsByName("section-36-control$xf-771$xf-784$xml_termin_platnosci-control$xforms-input-1")(0).Value)
2. TerminPlatnosci = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).getElementsByName("input id")(0).getAttribute("value"))
3. TerminPlatnosci = Trim(Doc.querySelector("input[name='section-36-control$xf-771$xf-784$xml_termin_platnosci-control$xforms-input-1']").getAttribute("value"))

Range("A1").Value = TerminPlatnosci

Comment: Which line does it stop on when you get `Object variable or With block variable not set`?

Comment: Any code starting with TerminPlatnosci

Comment: Before using `getAttribute` or `Trim`, save the results of `Doc.querySelector` into a variable so you can check to make sure it returned something first. You can't get attributes from something it cannot find.

Comment: please provide this piece of code to save the result of Doc.querySelector in a variable.  I'm trying to define variables in the same way as the others, but I'm getting errors.  I'm a beginner in VBA, so here's my request